# Как добавить еще одну колонку к таблице при SELECT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, bigquery

У меня есть SQL запрос 
Вот он:

```
SELECT AVG(data.page_load_time) AS Value, COUNT(data.page_load_time) AS Num, data.access_technology, data.carrier_name, data.cell_id, geo_areas.Name_2 AS area_name, pixel.area AS pixel_id FROM
      (SELECT id, page_load_time, access_technology, carrier_name, cell_id, latitude, longitude  FROM `cell-rebel-production.postgre_exports.mobile_page_load_metric_v2` 
      WHERE (page_load_time >=1) AND (page_load_time <=60000))data

    JOIN `cell-rebel-production.indo_geo_file.idn_adm_2_kabkota` geo_areas ON ST_Intersects(geo_areas.polygon, ST_GEOGPOINT(data.longitude, data.latitude))
    JOIN `cell-rebel-production.indo_geo_file.Jakarta_100m` pixel ON ST_Intersects(pixel.geometry, ST_GEOGPOINT(data.longitude, data.latitude))
    GROUP BY pixel_id, area_name, data.cell_id, data.access_technology, data.carrier_name
```

Вот результат запроса:

```
Value   Num access_technology   carrier_name    cell_id     area_name       pixel_id
2334    3   WiFi                3 - dirumahAja  65244047    Jakarta Timur   Jak_81228
1584    12  3G                  Axis            5135849     Jakarta Utara   Jak_35136
1222    4   4G                  IND TELKOMSEL   110762766   Jakarta Pusat   Jak_53555
```

К этой таблице я хочу добавить еще одну колонку с названием `Aggregation` и значением '`average`' для всех результатов запроса.

Т. е. должно быть вот так

```
Value   Num access_technology   carrier_name    cell_id     area_name       pixel_id   Aggregation
2334    3   WiFi                3 - dirumahAja  65244047    Jakarta Timur   Jak_81228  average
1584    12  3G                  Axis            5135849     Jakarta Utara   Jak_35136  average
1222    4   4G                  IND TELKOMSEL   110762766   Jakarta Pusat   Jak_53555  average
```

Я бы хотел это сделать прямо одним запросом.
Как я могу это сделать? 
Спасибо

Comment: `SELECT (всё, что там выводится сейчас), 'average' AS Aggregation FROM (всё остальное)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете выводить любую константу указав её в `select` подобно всем другим выводимым данным.

```
select 1 as fieldname, 'somestring' as fieldname2
```